# Format String to Date where input column has two different date formats

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column of strings that are in two different formats that need to be formatted as dates.

The column of strings (where one case has a time, and the other has no time)is:

```
orig_column
April 22, 20229:00AM
October 31, 2022
May 1, 202211:00pm
```

The outcome of dates should look like:

```
new_col
April 22, 2022
October 31, 2022
May 1, 2022
```

I original asked this question not knowing some records had times, and some without. This solution was suggested, which works, but can't handle the records where there are no times. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
select original_col, 
  format_datetime('%B %d, %Y %R%p', parse_datetime('%B %d, %Y%R%p', original_col)) as new_col
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below

```
select original_col, 
  ifnull(format_date('%B %d, %Y', safe.parse_datetime('%B %d, %Y%R%p', original_col)), original_col) as new_col
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]